# Format and print list of tuples as one line

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list containing tuples that is generated from a database query and it looks something like this.

```
[(item1, value1), (item2, value2), (item3, value3),...]
```

The tuple will be mixed length and when I print the output it will look like this.

```
item1=value1, item2=value2, item3=value3,...
```

I have looked for a while to try to find a solution and none of the `.join()` solutions I have found work for this type of situation.

Comment: Whatever it is called.... I thought it was a tuple.  What is it?

Comment: I think @user2357112 was pointing out that you have a `list` than contains `tuples`... The main item itself isn't a tuple... the `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're after something like:

```
>>> a = [('val', 1), ('val2', 2), ('val3', 3)]
>>> ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*el) for el in a)
'val=1, val2=2, val3=3'
```

This also doesn't care what type the tuple elements are... you'll get the `str` representation of them automatically.

Comment: *`This also doesn't care what type the tuple elements`* that is why its an excellent answer indeed.

Answer (score 3):

If each tuple is only an `(item, value)` pair then this should work:

```
l = [(item1, value1), (item2, value2), (item3, value3), ...]
', '.join('='.join(t) for t in l)
'item1=value1, item2=value2, item3=value3, ...'
```

Comment: The inner `join` works on each `(item, value)` pair and turns each one into `item=value`. At that point you essentially have a list of `["item1=value1", "item2=value2", "item3=value3", ...]. The outter `join` works on each of the `"item=value"` and combines them with a comma and a space to form the final result

Comment: OK because `'='.join('a','b')` == `a=b` so `'='.join(t) for t in l` will give me a list like `["item1=value1", "item2=value2", "item3=value3"..`  then you use Outer join to concat, by `,` .Got it Thanks for your response. But I have a doubt. Do we need `*` as `'='.join(t) for t in l` should be `'='.join(*t) for t in l` ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Using `*` in the `join` will give you an error saying that `join()` takes exactly one argument. The only argument join can take is an iterable `t` in this case. Perhaps @Jon Clements's use of `*` in `format` is confusing you. In that case, without the `*` only one argument (a tuple) would be passed to `format`, which would be used to populate the first `{}`. This would raise an error because the string is expecting **two** positional arguments. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/1507867) answer for more information on unpacking arguments in python.

Comment: I think got it now..So I wrote in comment `'='.join('a','b')` I should be  `'='.join( ('a','b') )` **?**  Thanks again man! you answer and comment are very helpful to me.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yup! Looks like you got it. One thing to keep in mind is that `join()` takes an iterable, so `'='.join(['a', 'b'])` will also work. For me, trying out these syntax questions in the python interpreter helps a lot.

Comment: This is a beautiful trick! It also works for `N>2` dimensional tuples!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools` as well

```
from itertools import starmap
', '.join(starmap('{}={}'.format, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [('item1', 'value1'), ('item2', 'value2'), ('item3', 'value3')]
print ', '.join(str(x) + '=' + str(y) for x, y in lst)
```

I'm explicitly converting to string the items and values, if one (or both) are already strings you can remove the corresponding `str()` conversion:

```
print ', '.join(x + '=' + y for x, y in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is this, definitely the shortest code

```
>>> a = [('val', 1), ('val2', 2), ('val3', 3)]
>>>', '.join('%s=%s' % v for v in a)
'val=1, val2=2, val3=3'
```

works with python 2.7 as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like that, I would use a dictionary.

```
dict = {1:2,3:4}
print dict
```

Then, you can loop through it like this:

```
dict = {1:2,3:3}
print dict

for i in dict:
    print i, "=", dict[i]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why dictionary? OP is not doing key lookups.